# Null check operator use on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   const SizedBox(height: 10),
    Flexible(
     child: StreamBuilder( //here the error i'm not so sure
     stream: ref.snapshots(),
     builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
      if(snapshot.hasError){
        return Center(
           child: Text("Error:${snapshot.error}"),
       );
      }

     return Scrollbar(
        child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 15,
          crossAxisSpacing: 15,
          childAspectRatio: 2/3,
        ),
           itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
           itemBuilder: (context,index) {

         final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
          return Card(
            shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
           elevation: 0,
           child: InkWell(
           onTap: (){
           Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(
type:PageTransitionType.leftToRight,
            child: DetailPage(
image:documentSnapshot['image'],                                             category:documentSnapshot['category'],                                             name:documentSnapshot['name'],                                            description:documentSnapshot['description'],                                          price:documentSnapshot['price'],
  )));
},

 child: Container(
   margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
      Ink.image(image: NetworkImage(documentSnapshot['image'][0]),
      height: 90,
      width: double.infinity,),
          const SizedBox(height: 5,),
          RichText(
           textAlign: TextAlign.start,
           text: TextSpan(
           text: documentSnapshot['category'],
           style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 12.0)),
           ),
```

i used this code to display product on the homepage but it just glimpse appear the error of null value but i still can run and display the product then how i should fix the code. Logic error.
This is my full code of the streamBuilder

Comment: Your code example should not compile in the first place... what does your `builder` function return if there is no error? Did you leave that out for this example, or is that actually your error?

Comment: it show the null value error on my android device but the product still can display

Comment: itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context,index) {

                                    final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                                    return Card(
                                      shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                      ),
                                      elevation: 0,
                                      child: InkWell(

Comment: should i change snapshot.data! to snapshot.data?

Comment: You should edit your post to include your full code. I cannot say anything about it, as long as it's bits and pieces.